# Problem with displaying the xAxis string values of LineChartView

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I have a problem with displaying the string values over the LineChartView in swift. I am using the following code, but it is displaying them with a jumping over one https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyCJ3.jpg, like on the image, it is moving from Jan to Mar but there is value for Feb. How I can fix this.

```
@objc(BarChartFormatter)
public class BarChartFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter
{
    var months: [String]! = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

    public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String
    {
        return months[Int(value)]
    }
}

chart.xAxis.wordWrapEnabled = true
//        chart.xAxis.isWordWrapEnabled = true
//        y.titleLocation = CPTDecimalFromFloat(150.0)
        for number in 0..<(SecondSwipe.months.count-1) {
            formato.stringForValue(Double(number), axis: xaxis)
        }
        xaxis.valueFormatter = formato
        chart.xAxis.valueFormatter = xaxis.valueFormatter
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to tell chart how many labels you want to show on **XAxis**. Use the below property to show all labels.

```
lineChartView.xAxis.labelCount = months.count
```

By setting label count it will show all labels on your xAxis.